# Changing every other letter in a string (JavaScript)? Each new word starts 0 based

Tags: javascript

I have this mostly working, but when certain letters are next to each other it's not doing the uppercase to them. Any ideas why it's missing them? My code and the expected outcome is below. The problem is with the "ooooo's", and "Looks"...

```js
function toWeirdCase(string) {
  var splitStr = string.split(" ");
  var newArr = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < splitStr.length; j++) {
    var letters = splitStr[j].split("");
    for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
      if (letters.indexOf(letters[i]) % 2 === 0) {
        letters[i] = letters[i].toUpperCase();
      }
    }
    newArr.push(letters.join(""));
  }
  console.log(newArr.join(" "));
}

console.log(toWeirdCase('ooooo')); //Should return 'OoOoO'
console.log(toWeirdCase('howdy')); //Should return 'HoWdY'
console.log(toWeirdCase('Looks')); //Should return 'LoOkS'
console.log(toWeirdCase('This')); //Should return 'ThIs'
console.log(toWeirdCase('is')); //Should return 'Is'
console.log(toWeirdCase('This is a test')); //Should return 'ThIs Is A TeSt'`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ES6 solution.

```js
function toWeirdCase(str){
  return str.split('').map((v,i) => i % 2 ? v.toLowerCase(): v.toUpperCase()).join('');
}

console.log(toWeirdCase('ooooo')); 
console.log(toWeirdCase('howdy')); 
console.log(toWeirdCase('Looks')); 
console.log(toWeirdCase('This')); 
console.log(toWeirdCase('is'));
console.log(toWeirdCase('This is a test'));
```

Your previous solution.

```js
function toWeirdCase(string) {
  var splitStr = string.split(" ");
  var newArr = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < splitStr.length; j++) {
    var letters = splitStr[j].split("");
    for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        letters[i] = letters[i].toUpperCase();
      } else {
        letters[i] = letters[i].toLowerCase();
      }
    }
    newArr.push(letters.join(""));
  }
  return newArr.join(" ");
}

console.log(toWeirdCase('ooooo')); 
console.log(toWeirdCase('howdy')); 
console.log(toWeirdCase('Looks')); 
console.log(toWeirdCase('This')); 
console.log(toWeirdCase('is'));
console.log(toWeirdCase('This is a test'));
```

**Edit**: You asked, why your solution didn't work. It didn't because of following line:

```
if (letters.indexOf(letters[i]) % 2 === 0) {
```

If, e.g. you had a word containing the same letters, like 'ooooo', the condition `letters.indexOf(letters[i]) % 2 === 0` was returning `0` (`false`) all the time, then your `if` condition was never true - so the loop didn't affect any letter.

Comment: Got downvoted for actually working code. I just love SO community xD

Comment: Finally someone open-minded upvoted my answer. Don't know who you are, but thanks tho. Really appreciated.

Comment: I like your answer using ES6 and your refactoring! Not sure why my original code was missing the other letters, but both approaches you gave works as it should... Thank you, and I'll choose yours for being first, and for offering more than one way to solve this... Thanks to the others too for all your efforts!!

Comment: In the interest of learning as much as I can, isn't letters[i] looking at the next item in the array? letters[0], letters[1}, letters[2], etc. and evaluating them individually? Is there something I can read/study that explains this?

Comment: @RDaniels34 Yes, it does :) But the `.indexOf()` function will always return `0`. You can check it in the console.

Comment: From MDN: The indexOf() method returns the (FIRST INDEX - emphasis mine) at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present. Hence, the first found is at  index 0... Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: @RDaniels34 My pleasure. You can mark my answer as the best one :)

Answer (score 0):

Kind user answer is great, but here is another one, which works on older browsers.

```js
function toWeirdCase(string) {
    string = string.split("");
    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if (string.hasOwnProperty(i) && i != 'length' && i % 2 == 0) {
            string[i] = string[i].toUpperCase();
        }
    }
    string = string.join("");
    console.log(string);
}

toWeirdCase('ooooo');
toWeirdCase('howdy');
toWeirdCase('Looks');
toWeirdCase('This');
toWeirdCase('is');
toWeirdCase('This is a test');
```

Answer (score 0):

A small function with a loop:

```js
function toWeirdCase(getString){
 var returned = '';
 for(var i=0;i<getString.length;i++){
  var method = i%2===0 ? 'toUpperCase':'toLowerCase';
  returned += getString[i][method]();
 }
 return returned;
}

console.log(toWeirdCase('Looks'));
```

Answer (score 0):

May be helpful to split up logic between the word => WeirdCase transformation and the phrase => WeirdCase transformation:

```js
function evenUpperCase(letter, i) {
  return i % 2 === 0 ? letter.toUpperCase() : letter.toLowerCase();
} 

function wordToWeirdCase(word) {
  return word.split('')
    .map(evenUpperCase)
    .join('');
}

function phraseToWeirdCase(phrase) {
  return phrase.split(' ')
    .map(wordToWeirdCase)
    .join(' ');
}

console.log(phraseToWeirdCase('ooooo')); //Should return 'OoOoO'
console.log(phraseToWeirdCase('howdy')); //Should return 'HoWdY'
console.log(phraseToWeirdCase('Looks')); //Should return 'LoOkS'
console.log(phraseToWeirdCase('This')); //Should return 'ThIs'
console.log(phraseToWeirdCase('is')); //Should return 'Is'
console.log(phraseToWeirdCase('This is a test'));
```